# Git push resulted in different user

Tags: git, push

I was using public WIFI when pushing changes to the Git. But when checked who committed I got different user.

[image]

But I also had this error when pushing to master but still able to push.

[image]

Could someone explain why it happened and is it security concern?

Comment: in the future, its usually better to use [git+ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) for your repos

Comment: Your two commits both appear to be from the same user. If anything, your email address isn't associated with your Git profile. I wouldn't say it's a security concern. What I would say is that you shouldn't be pushing directly to `master`; learn Git Flow :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your git configuration:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

The email must be the one from your GitHub account.